# GithubActions commit without pull/checkout

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a workflow in Github Actions that adds various files to a repository. These commands run on a Linux virtual machine (azure).

I would like to commit certain files to the repository without downloading and checking out the entire repository first. The repository is quite large, and it takes a long time to download. The workflow is executed from within the repository where the files are to be added.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can [use the Contents REST API to directly create/overwrite a file in a git repo](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-file-contents).

```
curl -L \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/contents/PATH \
  -d '{"message":"my commit message","committer":{"name":"Monalisa Octocat","email":"octocat@github.com"},"content":"bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="}'
Response
```

This will allow you to change the repo contents without having to clone the repository.

You can either use CURL (as shown above) or PowerShell or the github cli (`gh api ...`).

You can use the `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` to authorize the REST call.